# How to get Friends e-mails

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use FacebookSDK_V5.0.3 to interact with Facebook. I've created a Facebook application (AppX) and a Facebook user (UserX) and granted all permissions regarding UserX to AppX. Now, I want AppX to access UserX friends e-mails addresses. Is it possible?

I've already managed to get UserX friends through the following code.

var fb = new FacebookClient(AppId, SecretKey);
   dynamic friends = fb.Get("UserX/friends");

I've tried many approaches to get the friends e-mails, but I couldn't. I can't access user info directly because AppX doesn't have permissions to read, but if can through UserX...

Thanks a lot,
Leonardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  A user has to explicitly grant you the email extended permission for you to retrieve their email address.  It is not enough that their friend granted you that permission.

Comment: Thanks Pat.

Probably I'm not using the correct approach... 

I've a website were users subscribe and introduce their e-mails. I also have a Facebook account with many friends. I just want to build a simple .net app that allows me to map my website user accounts with my facebook account friends.

This .net application is to be used as a server process so it can't have user interface. Is it possible to do this?